# PHP parse multidimensional array with json

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to parse a json string extracted from a MySQL database. The json string contains a two-dimensional array, but json_decode returns null and json_last_error returns 0 which I assume means no error occurred.

$result is the json string

```
json_decode($result, true);
```

The string:

```
[
 ["17544500374","17544500489","17544500571","17544500587","17544500528"],
 ["17544500651","17544500432","17544500673","17544500452","17544500362"],
 ["17544500454","17544500457","17544500523","17544500441"],
 ["17544500547","17544500463","17544500535","17544500676"],
 ["17544500548","17544500581","17544500584","17544500382"],
 ["17544500593","17544500364","17544500660","17544500595"],
 ["17544500635","17544500647","17544500529","17544500670"]
]
```

Comment: You do not have key value pair to make proper json

Comment: Parsing it on the JavaScript side works fine.

Comment: Show us all the relevant code

Comment: Share the code where you store json

Comment: Do we assume this is the PHP array AFTER you have json_decoded it?

Comment: Show us `$result` before you decode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a key for your values. That means, your second parameter is not correct, because the function is unable to create an associative array.

This works fine on my mashine:

```
json_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$result` must be a string:

```
$result = '[["17544500374","17544500489","17544500571","17544500587","17544500528"],["17544500651","17544500432","17544500673","17544500452","17544500362"],["17544500454","17544500457","17544500523","17544500441"],["17544500547","17544500463","17544500535","17544500676"],["17544500548","17544500581","17544500584","17544500382"],["17544500593","17544500364","17544500660","17544500595"],["17544500635","17544500647","17544500529","17544500670"]]'
```